# Is this correct way to deep clone array of objects as property inside object?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this reducer.

```
const userInitialState = {
  users: [],
};

const users = (state = userInitialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "FETCH_USERS") {
    return {
      ...state,
      users: action.payload,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export default combineReducers({
  users,
});
```

initially the users property is edmpty array,when the new results from the api call comes

for example response like
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

is this the correct way for immutable way in redux store for my array inside ?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

A proper immutable update is best described as "a nested shallow clone".  You don't want to copy *every* value in a nested data structure - just the ones that need to be updated.

But yes, that looks correct.

A couple additional observations:

- You should read through the post [The Complete Guide to Immutability in React and Redux](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/) and the Redux docs page on [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) to better understand how to do immutable updates correctly
- But, you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), which uses Immer to let you write "mutating" update logic that is turned into safe and correct immutable updates.